# Can this inaccessible area be made link, only with CSS?

Tags: php, css, html, drupal

I have to manage a website witch have the following situation:

We have a banner system on the website, but the banners are clickable only on small area. I want to make them all clickable, but there are some limitations.

I don`t have access to php files and I can manage HTML after certain level.
Currently I can manage only small area which is marked on the image.
[Example of the area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3OwB.jpg)

Every code that I write is placed only in this marked area. There is no way to make whole banner clickable, because there is no that kind of option on GUI.
I think that I can target with CSS classes that are above that area, but can`t edit the HTML.

Is there an option to make all this area clickable without messing everything up?

Here is the full HTML code of one banner:

```html
<li class="flex-active-slide" style="width: 1583px; float: left; display: block;">
  <div class="image-flexslider-content-left clearfix">
    <div class="views-field views-field-field-slider-image">
      <div class="field-content"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="/example-image.png" alt="" draggable="false" style="margin-left: -84.25px; height: 510px;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="white">
    <div class="logo-big mobile-logo">
      <h1 class="logo">
        <a href="/" title="Lorem"></a>
      </h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper-container white">
    <div class="logo-big">
      <h1 class="logo">
        <a href="/" title="Lorem"></a>
      </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="slide-cover flexslider-content-left">
      <div class="views-field views-field-title"> <span class="field-content"></span> </div>
      <div class="views-field views-field-body">
        <div class="field-content">
          <a href="/something/more/">
            <div class="double-container">
              <p class="double-blue-head larger-head" style="font-size: 2.4rem !important; font-weight: bold;">Line of text 1</p>
            </div>
            <div class="double-container">
              <p class="double-blue-head larger-head" style="font-size: 2.4rem !important; font-weight: bold;">Line of text 2</p>
            </div>
          </a>
          <div class="double-container blue-responsive double-blue-head larger-head myt-margin" style="padding: 10px 12px  15px 20px; margin-top: 40px;">
            <a href="/something/more/"> <img src="/images/example.png" style="width:100% !Important; max-width:435px !Important; margin-top: 10px; height:auto !important;" draggable="false"></a>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="views-field views-field-contextual-links"> <span class="field-content"></span> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Can you insert/add JavaScript at all?

Comment: Yes I can add JavaScript

Comment: @Petyo.DImitrov Please see my answer below for how to make your banner clickable with JavaScript. Let me know if that doesn't answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With JavaScript, you can add an [event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers) to make any element on the page clickable.  So for example, if you want to make one of the `<div class="field-content">` elements clickable, you would add an event handler like this (assuming you want to make the first one clickable for this example):

```
document.querySelectorAll("div.field-content")[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
    // your code here; whatever you want to happen when they click
});
```

You can apply event handlers to any of the HTML elements on your page.  If you apply it to a parent element, then it will also be triggered when a child element is clicked, so you can make your whole banner clickable just by adding an event handler to the banner's outer element.

**UPDATE:** To apply the click handler to an entire class, use a `for` loop, like this:

```
var banners = document.getElementsByClassName("field-content");
for (var i = 0; i < banners.length; i++) {
    banners[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        location.href = "yourURL";
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problems is that I have no idea what to add in area for my code. What should add to trigger the event?

Comment: @PetyoDImitrov It depends on which element(s) you want to trigger the event. Do you know which elements you want to add the click handler to?

Comment: I want .field-content and everything below to be clickable and to trigger the only <a> into the code.

Comment: If you want each element with the `.field-content` class to have the click handler, you would use a `for` loop to loop through the elements (as `document.getElementsByClassName('field-content')[i]`) and assign the click handler to each element.

Comment: the problem is that I don`t know how to do this :(

Comment: @PetyoDImitrov Okay, no worries, I can help you with that. What do you mean by "to trigger the only `<a>` into the code?" Do you mean that whenever any item with the class `field-content` is clicked, it will load the link that you have specified in your `<a>` element?

Comment: Sorry for the late respond. That is exactly I want to happend. On the website there are 5 banners and every one of them have same structure, I want users to have ability to click on the.field-content and that to lead them to defined by me url. I doesn't matter if I have to define it or it can be taken from the only <a>. Of course if the second option is possible it will be perfect.

Comment: @PetyoDImitrov I've updated my answer to include how to add the click handler to the whole `field-content` class. Is that what you meant?

Comment: I try to add only the updated version of your code, but now banners do not show up. Also if I check in Chrome I have an error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )"

Comment: @PetyoDImitrov That's my fault... I forgot the closing `}` for my `for` loop.  I added it in my answer -- it should work for you now.

Comment: Still no success. Part of the problem can be that this area .field-content is not clickable, so maybe that is reason why the script can not be triggered.

Comment: @PetyoDImitrov Why are the `field-content` elements not clickable? They are `div`s, correct?

Comment: Please excuse me for the delayed answer.

Comment: The problem is that only the area after .field-content is clicakble, because there is an <a> and actual link there. The code there is a little bit messy, so I only need to find a way to make .image-flexslider-content-left clearfix clickable and to have <a>

Comment: In other classes there are logos and part ot the menu, so should not be changed. Now the only task is how to make clickable .image-flexslider-content-left clearfix but don't have access to this level of code.

Comment: If you can insert JavaScript, you can add a click handler using the same method as shown in my answer, but just substituting the `.image-flexslider-content-left` class for the class that's currently there.

Comment: I receive _undefined_ as a result in Chrome console when i paste this:

`var banners = document.getElementsByClassName("image-flexslider-content-left");
for (var i = 0; i < banners.length; i++) {
    banners[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        location.href = "www.appovete.com";
    });
}`

Comment: Try adding this line after you declare the `banners` variable to see if it is grabbing the class list correctly: `alert(banners.length);`  It should give you the number of elements with that class.  Does it do that?

Answer (score 1):

You could move the  tag outside of the entire div class="field-content"

```
<a href="/something/more/">
     <div class="field-content">
        
            <div class="double-container">
              <p class="double-blue-head larger-head" style="font-size: 2.4rem !important; font-weight: bold;">Line of text 1</p>
            </div>
            <div class="double-container">
              <p class="double-blue-head larger-head" style="font-size: 2.4rem !important; font-weight: bold;">Line of text 2</p>
            </div>
          <div class="double-container blue-responsive double-blue-head larger-head myt-margin" style="padding: 10px 12px  15px 20px; margin-top: 40px;">
            <a href="/something/more/"> <img src="/images/example.png" style="width:100% !Important; max-width:435px !Important; margin-top: 10px; height:auto !important;" draggable="false"></a>
          </div>

        </div>
</a>
```

Comment: I don't have access before .field-content but want to make also elements above part of the link